# Can I have multiple threads post to the UI Simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, java-threads

I am creating my first Android App using Java. At onCreate I have a number of methods that set up the size/positions of cardViews, size of text, background images and so on. Because of the amount of pre-work, it takes a few seconds for my app to load when I first open it.

I'm thinking about dividing the labor among a number of background threads that can run simultaneously to speed up the app's initial setup. ***However, can I have multiple threads running at the same time that will post info on the main UI?***

For example: I could launch threadA, threadB and threadC at onCreate - threadA assigns the size/color of text for210 textViews on the main UI, threadB assigns the length/width of 20 cardViews on the main UI and threadC assigns the x/y locations of the 20 cardViews on the main UI.

With so much feeding to the main UI from so many background threads at once, am I courting disaster? Like a freezing up/App not responding issues? Could this approach be problematic?

Comment: "can I have multiple threads running at the same time that will post info on the main UI?" -- no

Comment: If these size calculations are so expensive (profile it to find out) that you can't do them on the UI thread you could pre-calculate the dimensions etc on a background thread, but you must do the actual updating of views on the UI thread. If all you're doing is setting text/size/location/color attributes though you should just do that on the UI thread. Think of it this way, if you have 200 TextViews the UI thread is already going to be handling drawing and laying out those views. Your setting of some attributes on them isn't going to be a performance issue.

Comment: Also, have you verified that "*Because of the amount of pre-work*, it takes a few seconds for my app to load" is actually true, or are you just assuming it's true? Take out all the pre-work you think makes it slow, time it, and see how long it takes

Answer (score 0):

The UI (Main) thread is synchronous. If you have background threads the data should be posted to the UI thread before UI is changed, at that point all calls are synchronous. The application may crash/freeze if you attempt to update UI elements from a thread other than main.

Here is an example of runnable setting a background thread to UI (Main) thread . Note that "application" variable is Context. Research Android View Model, LiveData and Observers for other examples.

```
if (application != null && object != null){
        Handler mainHandler = new Handler(application.getMainLooper());
        Runnable myRunnable = () -> {
            tokenLiveData.setValue(object);
        };
        mainHandler.post(myRunnable);
    }
```